# VBA Automation isn't working on new IE tab

Tags: excel, vba, internet-explorer

It's my first question and I'm new on VBA.

I was trying to run a macro to automatize some procedures on IE. My macro worked very well when opened on diferent windows, but when I tried to run the same macro on tabs it didn't work. It seems (maybe) the macro isn't recognizing the actual tab. Could anyone help me, please?

```
Sub Test1()

    Dim IE As Object
    Dim doc As HTMLDocument
    Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")

    For intRow = 1 To 3

    If intRow = 1 Then

        With IE
            .Visible = True
            .navigate "https://gru.inpi.gov.br/pePI/jsp/patentes/PatenteSearchBasico.jsp"

        Do While IE.Busy Or IE.readyState <> 4
            Application.Wait DateAdd("s", 1, Now)
        Loop

        Set doc = IE.document

            IE.document.getElementById("principal").Children(4). _
                getElementsByTagName("tbody")(0).getElementsByTagName("tr")(5). _
                getElementsByTagName("td")(1).getElementsByTagName("font")(0). _
                getElementsByTagName("input")(0).Value = "intRow"

                Application.Wait DateAdd("s", 2, Now)


        End With
    Else
        With IE
            .Visible = True
            .navigate "https://gru.inpi.gov.br/pePI/jsp/patentes/PatenteSearchBasico.jsp", 2048&

        Do While IE.Busy Or IE.readyState <> 4
            Application.Wait DateAdd("s", 1, Now)
        Loop

            .document.getElementById("principal").Children(4). _
                getElementsByTagName("tbody")(0).getElementsByTagName("tr")(5). _
                getElementsByTagName("td")(1).getElementsByTagName("font")(0). _
                getElementsByTagName("input")(0).Value = "intRow"

                Application.Wait DateAdd("s", 2, Now)

        End With    
    End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Can you give more detail about what "didn't work" means. What should happen and what is happening in the code above? Do you get errors?

Comment: Sure, im pretending to navigate trought tabs and fill the input's from a excel file.
I managed to do this through new windows, but not through the same tab. The answer from Zhi Lv, worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

According to your code and the website, it seems that you want to open multiple tab (with the same URL), and then fill a value in the text box. We should pay attention to the following point:

1. How to access the web page elements.
2. How to switch tabs and focus to the new tab.

To access the web page elements, from your web page resource (use F12 developer tools to check it), I notice that the table contains 6 rows, but the last row doesn't contain the input element. So, using your code, I can't find the input element. I found that the input elements contain the class property. So, I suggest you could use the getElementsByClassName method to find the element.

To switch the IE browser tab, we could loop through the opened tabs and compare the URL, and then set focus on the related tab.

More detail steps, please check the following sample code:

```
 Sub Test1()

    Dim IE As Object
    Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")

    Dim intRow As Integer
    For intRow = 1 To 3

    If intRow = 1 Then

        With IE
            .Visible = True
            .navigate "https://gru.inpi.gov.br/pePI/jsp/patentes/PatenteSearchBasico.jsp"

        Do While IE.Busy Or IE.readyState <> 4
            Application.Wait DateAdd("s", 1, Now)
        Loop

        Set doc = IE.document

            IE.document.getElementsByClassName("basic")(0).Value = "intRow" & intRow

            Application.Wait DateAdd("s", 3, Now)


        End With
    Else
        With IE
            .Visible = True
            .navigate "https://gru.inpi.gov.br/pePI/jsp/patentes/PatenteSearchBasico.jsp", 2048&

        Do While IE.Busy Or IE.readyState <> 4
            Application.Wait DateAdd("s", 1, Now)
        Loop

            Application.Wait DateAdd("s", 3, Now)
            Set IE = GetIE("https://gru.inpi.gov.br/pePI/jsp/patentes/PatenteSearchBasico.jsp")

            Application.Wait DateAdd("s", 3, Now)
            IE.document.getElementsByClassName("basic")(0).Value = "intRow" & intRow


        End With
    End If
    Next
End Sub


Function GetIE(sLocation As String) As Object

        Dim retVal As Object
        Dim my_url As String, my_title As String
        Set objShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
        IE_count = objShell.Windows.Count

        'loop through the window and find the tab


        For x = 0 To (IE_count - 1)
            On Error Resume Next
            'get the location and title
            my_url = objShell.Windows(x).document.Location
            my_title = objShell.Windows(x).document.Title

            'debug to check the value
            Debug.Print x
            Debug.Print my_url
            'find the special tab based on the title.
            If my_url Like sLocation Then
                Set retVal = objShell.Windows(x)
                'IE.Quit 'call the Quit method to close the tab.
                'Exit For   'exit the for loop
            Else
            End If
        Next

    Set GetIE = retVal

End Function
```

After running the above script, it will open three tabs and fill a value in the Login input text. Please see the following screenshot:

[image]

Reference:

[Common VBA Methods & Properties used in web automation](http://automatetheweb.net/common-vba-methods-properties-web-automation/)

Comment: _.Visible = True_ has already been set so is not needed later in the script. I would also use an IIF to test value of _intRow_ to determine whether open in new tab and thereby do away with entire _else_ section.

Comment: Thank you very much, the code worked for what I wanted. There's an abnormal thing in the access of this website of the Brazilian patent office. When I access for the first time directly through the link: https://gru.inpi.gov.br/pePI/jsp/patentes/PatenteSearchBasico.jsp
I'm redirected for this login page, but when I access the same link through this other page http://www.inpi.gov.br/ by clicking on "Faça uma busca" in the right corner, then I go to the page I want. Subsequent access, even through the direct link, results in the page I want and not this login page. Thank you again.